# JPOS Sample Application User and Password

Tags: javapos

Is it possible to create a barcode for my user and password  to scan?

I open the JPOS app to work I have a barcode for the password when it is alone and it works but when I go to POS it asks for the user tab password enter.

I already have the barcode but the program is not accepting the tab function.

I am not sure if it's because it's a log in page.

Thanks for any help possible.

Comment: There is no concept or specification for user names or passwords in barcode data, and barcode readers do not have the functionality to handle them. There is no system that will do these things automatically. In order to realize them, you need to design the specifications and implement the system yourself.